# python with selenium: drag and drop from local to webdrive

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import webDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_condition as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.by import by
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time
import os
import date

options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option(useAutomationExtention', False)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r"Driver path")
drive.get('portal path')
os,chdir('c:\\user\download')
downloads_local=os.getcwd()+'\\'
source_file=downloads_local+Filename'.zip'
targetpage='//*[@id="BrowserDiv"]'
target_downloads=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,targetpage)))
time.sleep(10)
ActionChain(driver).click_and_hold(source_file).move_the_element(target_page).release(target_page).perform()
```

> Error: AttributeError : move to requires a element I also tried to
> browse the file but the file search window opens unable to search the
> file. Error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: PLease add some explanation on what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: I am trying to drag and drop a file from local machine to share portal